Otp authentication based captive portal
I want to build a otp based captive portal. Can anyone suggest how to configure it on the Cisco Meraki platform or any other AP/platform?
I have tried with Meraki's sign on with radius server and the feature of custom splash page but not working. I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I have installed the freeradius. The authentication works fine without splash page. But how to integrate external otp based splash page, freeradius, and Meraki platform?
